# Scala MongoDB connection using Mongo4cats not working

Tags: mongodb, scala

This is my `scala` main method

```
import cats.effect.{IO, Resource}
import mongo4cats.client._
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import mongo4cats.bson.ObjectId
import mongo4cats.circe._

import java.time.Instant

object Main extends App{
  val creditCard = CreditCard("John Bloggs", "1111222233334444", "1021", 919)
  val paypal = Paypal("hello.world@test.com")
  val payment1 = Payment(ObjectId(), BigDecimal(2.5), paypal, Instant.parse("2021-04-05T12:00:00Z"))
  val payment2 = Payment(ObjectId(), BigDecimal(9.99), creditCard, Instant.parse("2021-04-12T12:00:00Z"))

  val mongoClient: Resource[IO, MongoClient[IO]] =
    MongoClient.fromConnectionString[IO]("mongodb://root:secret@127.0.0.1:27017")

  mongoClient.use { client =>
    for {
      db <- client.getDatabase("testdb")
      coll <- db.getCollectionWithCodec[Payment]("payments")
      _ <- coll.insertOne(payment1)
      _ <- coll.insertMany(List(payment2))
    } yield ()
  }
}
```

This is my scala model/collection file

```
import mongo4cats.bson.ObjectId

import java.time.Instant
sealed trait PaymentMethod

final case class Paypal(email: String) extends PaymentMethod

final case class CreditCard(
                             name: String,
                             number: String,
                             expiry: String,
                             cvv: Int
                           ) extends PaymentMethod

final case class Payment(
                          id: ObjectId,
                          amount: BigDecimal,
                          method: PaymentMethod,
                          date: Instant
                        )
```

I was following one of the article to explore `Mongo4cats` but unable to make it work. Infact if I change the mongodb connection string , still script is not raising any exceptions.

My mongodb server is running fine and able to access using `mongo-shell` over `127.0.0.1:27017`

```
> show dbs
admin   0.000GB
config  0.000GB
local   0.000GB
```

Comment: You are not running your `IO` thus your program will never do anything at all. The quick solution is to use `IOApp.Simple` and override the `run` method. Moreover, if you are new to **cats-effect** I encourage you to join the **Typelevel** **Discord** server and check the resources that are pinned in the `#"beginners` channel.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance

Comment: It worked after implementing the suggestions. Thanks